# Material ui typography - font doubles in size - how come?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui v4.9.13 and react v16.13.1.

I have some code that basically generates some text like this:

```
                        <Typography variant="body1">
                          {description}
                        </Typography>
```

On the desktop that works nicely and the body1 style is applied correctly.

However, although it works correctly 90% of the time on Chrome running on Mobile, sometimes, the body1 style seems to double in size. eg.

[image]

And just occasionally, this:

[image]

Any ideas what's happening and how to solve it?

FYI, here's how I create the typography:

```
let theme = createMuiTheme ({
  spacing: 8,
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Manrope',
      'Roboto',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '-apple-system',
    ].join(','),
    fontSize: 1,
    fontWeightLight: 300,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    h1: {
      lineHeight: "2.2",
      fontSize:  "1.8em",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32',
    },
    h2: {
      lineHeight: "2",
      fontSize: "1.6em",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    h3: {
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      fontSize: "1.3em",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    h4: {
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      fontSize: "1.3em",
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#317aff'
    },
    h5: {
      lineHeight: "1",
      fontSize: "1.1em",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    h6: {
      lineHeight: "1",
      fontSize: "1em",
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    subtitle1: {
      lineHeight: "1",
      fontSize: "0.9em",
      fontWeight: 600,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    subtitle2: {
      lineHeight: "1",
      fontSize: "0.9em",
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    },
    body1: {
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      fontSize: "1.3em",
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32',
    },
    body2: {
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      fontSize: "1.3em",
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32',
    },
    caption: {
      fontSize: "0.9em",
      fontWeight: 700,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
    },
    button: {
      fontSize: "1.8em",
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontFamily: "\"Manrope\", \"Roboto\", \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"",
      color: '#001C32'
    }
  },
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
    background: {
      default: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#001C32",
      secondary: "#001C32"
    },
    primary: {
      main: '#929396'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#ff671e'
    },
    error: red,
    warning: orange,
    info: yellow,
    success: green,
  }
})

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme)
```

Comment: Body1 is the default variant of typography, you don't have to define it. However, maybe there are problems with chrome recognising it is in mobile state? Have you tried refershing the website when you open developer tools and enable mobile agent?

Comment: Refreshing fixes it and it displays properly. However, the issue will resurface again a few clicks later...

Comment: And I used Body1 as an example, but the same happens with h3, h2 etc. etc.

Comment: @MindaugasNakrosis - how do I "enable mobile agent"?

Comment: When in developer console you click "Toggle device toolbar" and select "Galaxy S5" user agent changes which tells your website which css should be applied (mobile or desktop, material-ui handles this with body1 variant). However, you need to refresh the page once you choose the agent so the website loads knowing already it is in "mobile mode". However, if the problem persists after refreshing I am not sure that is the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using @media in responsiveFontSizes as described here: https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes

Comment: @MindaugasNakrosis - ah, then I'm enabling mobile agent. And I run the site on an actual mobile, too, and it exhibits the same behaviour. I do things slightly differently to having to use direct media queries - instead, I use [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect) and instantiate the requisite theme file.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be the (un)helpful way the Chrome mobile browser scales fonts. The fix was this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1"">
```